# SP2016 - Change App Launcher Colour

Tags: 2016

With the recent introduction of being able to have custom tiles in the app launcher on Sharepoint 2016 ([Technet Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790697(v=office.16).aspx) ), does anyone know if it's possible to change the colour of the tiles from the default blue in order to match the theme of the sites?